# PowerBI barchart highlight

Tags: filter, powerbi, slicers

I have five organizations in one column and their value in different column.
I selected bar chart visuals showing every org's in x-axis and their values in y-axis. I have a slicer filter drop down of all organizations.
My question is when I select only one particular org in the slicer filter, I would like see **all the org's in the bar chart visuals** AND the **one org I selected should be highlighted or different than other bar** so that it can be easily noticeable.
How can I do this in Power BI? any help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Please share some sample data, expected output and codes you’ve written so far

Answer (score 0):

The best way to achieve this would be to not use a slicer and rather a table with just the organization names. You will be able to format the table to look more like a slicer by playing around with the visual settings in the visual.
This should give you the functionality that you are looking for as the users will be able to click on the name in the table and it will only highlight the bar that is being used. If it does not please check your settings and see if the cross filter setting is set to highlight.